# Youtube iframe loads a script that dosn't pass googl's page speed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube

i am using google page speed to test my wordpress site.

It is saying i need to "leverage browser caching", under it, it is mentioning a script:
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js

This script is coming from a youtube Iframe, how can i fix this ?

i tryed lazy loading the youtube iframe, but this error is still there, you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.agada4u.co.il%2F)

I was looking for a solution for this all over the web but didn't found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The ad_status.js is for the google/youtube advertising that loads along with an embedded youtube video. If you can access the youtube account for the video you can set options there to change how ads display.